# CSS from CDN with integrity loads twice

Tags: css, cdn

Is it normal for integrity and crossorigin to make stylesheets appear to load twice in Chrome inspector?

I am using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

when dropping the integrity and crossorigin attribute it only loads once. 
If it is not why could it be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some info about this issue [here](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf), if you're still looking.

> The `integrity` attribute for link elements has not yet been implemented and there’s an open spec issue about it. This means the presence of any integrity metadata will currently discard preloaded resources. In the wild, it can also result in duplicate requests where you have to make a trade-off between security and performance.